# HTML form - when I hit enter it refreshes page!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to make a form NOT refresh or call anything when you hit "Enter" key on your keyboard?

Thank you so much!!!

I found this code for preventing Enter from working, but it DOESN'T work in IE :(

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() { return false; });
});
```

Comment: a non-jquery answer to this would be nice since jquery is so outdated

Comment: @JohnMiller try something like  onSubmit={(e) => handleLogin(e)} and inside handleLogin function define this:    e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 25):

Disabling the `submit` event isn't a good idea. Now you can **never** submit the form by pressing the button where it is for.

Rather hook on the `keypress` event:

```
<form onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13">
```

or in jQuery flavor:

```
$('form').keypress(function(event) { 
    return event.keyCode != 13;
});
```

`13` is the keyCode of <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This works in all browsers from IE6 up to with all the current ones. You only have to take textareas into account. You may then consider this construct instead:

```
$(':input:not(textarea)').keypress(function(event) { 
    return event.keyCode != 13;
});
```

Answer (score 21):

add onSubmit property on form's tag.

```
<form onSubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: the simplest and best solution, imo

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent form submission by 'enter' key natively **if you are using AngularJS**.

According to HTML specification and AngularJS, you need to check this list:

1. Form must have **NO** `action=...` attribute (AngularJS handles it automatically)
2. Form must have **NO** `button` with `type="submit"` attribute

So, if you have no action attribute and submit button, then your form should not be submitted by hitting enter key.

Also, cross-browser keyCode is this:

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
```

Comment: I know this wasn't an AngularJS question but this worked a treat for me (using AngularJS).